# field_delim="\t" doesn't work properly in tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=listoflists,field_delim="\t") in tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning, theano

I have a tab seperated CSV file

I use the following code fragment

```
data = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=listoflists,field_delim="\t")
```

but it arises the following error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Expect 5 fields but have 1 in record 0
```

but when i make the file into comma separated and space separated , it works correctly

**1. Comma Sepeated**

```
   data = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=listoflists)
```

**2.Space Separated**

```
   data = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=listoflists,field_delim=" ")
```

**The full Code**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf

def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

filename = "test.csv"

# setup text reader
file_length = file_len(filename)
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename])
reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
_, csv_row = reader.read(filename_queue)

# setup CSV decoding


#setup text reader
listoflists = []
for i in range(0,5):
    listoflists.append((list([0])))

data = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=listoflists,field_delim="\t")

# turn features back into a tensor

print("loading, " + str(file_length) + " line(s)\n")
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

    # start populating filename queue
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for i in range(file_length):
        # retrieve a single instance
        example = sess.run(data)
        print(example)

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
    print("\ndone loading")
```

**Sample Data**

*Tab Separated :*

```
1   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0
```

*Comma Separated :*

```
1,0,1,1,1
1,0,1,1,1
1,0,1,1,1
1,0,1,1,1
1,0,1,1,1
1,0,1,1,1
```

*Space Separated :*

```
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Your sample data is not tab-separated but 3-spaces-separated. But my guess is, that this is rather a problem with copy/paste or most probably with the Code Sections in stackoverflow:

Comment: Thanks u @mkiever. I edit the text file in Intellij IDEA . Probably here the problem arises